# Get multiple columns for different WHERE clause on the same column in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, calculated-columns, having

I have a table and column containing `date` (say in string). I need to get two columns such as `countin(2020)` and `countin(2019)` from the same date column such that date is like '2020%' or '2019%' and I want them as separate columns.

My query is kind of like this.

```
select C.pin_code, count(distinct(C.customer_code)) as 2020 
from table 
group by C.pin_code
```

My output is this

[image]

For me there should be another column beside 2020 called 2019 which give same data as 2020 in year 2019.

If I have under emphasized something, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What does your data look like?  (3) What does your existing query have to do with year 2020?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Count(Year(year_col)) as year,
Pin_code
From T
Group_by pin_code
Order by pin_code desc;
```

You can use pivot in case you need those values in year column

Answer (score 0):

> For me there should be another column beside 2020 called 2019 which give same data as 2020 in year 2019.

If your data has a date in it, then I would expect a query like this:

```
select C.pin_code,
       count(distinct case when year(C.date) = 2020 then C.customer_code end) as cnt_2020, 
       count(distinct case when year(C.date) = 2019 then C.customer_code end) as cnt_2019
from C 
group by C.pin_code;
```

Date/time functions are notoriously database dependent.  But `year()` is pretty common and all databases have this functionality somehow.

Comment: Hii I get the error "Error while executing SQL query on database 'Salestable': no such function: year" I am using sqlite